# Generate integers with String to curve node and Simulation Nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, simulation-nodes

How do you generate a list of integers with String to curve (1, 2, 3, 4, etc)? I tried to with simulation nodes but the string to curve node does not have a geometry input socket.

Or is there a way to generate a list of numbers without simulation nodes? Without having to use several String to curve nodes.

[image]

Comment: It's unclear what integers you want to generate, why and how, and why you want to use simulation nodes. Simulation nodes are also not in current version. You are asking about functionality from unreleased experimental build so that is off-topic as well. Unreleased versions still in development may not work as intended yet and also may change before being released so answers may become irrelevant soon.

Comment: I want to use the string to curve node to generate the numbers 1, 2, 3, 4, . . .n. The setup must function similar to a while loop that prints out the integers in predefined increments. I know it's possible to just add the numbers 1 - 10 as a string into the String to curve node but that would become tedious if I wanted the list of integers from 1 - 100. I used simulation nodes because as far as I know it is the only nodes that can generate geometry iteratively.

Comment: If you just need to generate a string, you have Python in Blender. You can just write print( ', '.join(map(str, range(1,101)))) in the Python Console and just copy the output.

Comment: So I assume there is no combination of geometry nodes that can achieve this?

Comment: What's the context here? Why do you need geometry nodes to generate a range of number? Does it change depending on something in the scene?

Comment: @EdwardSerfontein: i have to agree with Martynas. I am not sure what you really want to achieve. I wrote an answer - but i fear your answer will be: "no, that's not what i wanted and then the explanation how you want it - will come, which should have been already in your question on the first time"

Comment: I am working on an alternative to manim. Not all math enthusiasts enjoy coding. So, I started by creating a procedural ,scalable, cartesian plane. I have the setup for the plane but I struggled to generate integers on the points of the axis. But the answer you posted is 100% what I want.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can use this node setup:

[image]

to get this:

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted! Thank you kindly

Comment: @Chris Thanks! I personally didn't understand the votes to close the OP.. must have been reading it differently,

Comment: @RobinBetts: i think the problem Martynas and i had is the "list of integers" because if you take it "word by word" it's a list of curves. As you saw in my answer i did try to interprete his question "the easy way" but i was prepared that i might waste my time (again - as i did a lot of times here because questions were asked with less or no details) - which is sometimes a bit frustrating

Comment: @EdwardSerfontein: you are welcome! i hope you forgive me that i was a bit negative because of my "a bit longer" experience here....

Comment: No problem at all! I appreciate your sharpness and dedication.